# Python: Must non-built-in exceptions be imported in order to catch them?

Tags: python, exception, python-requests

I'm trying to catch some exceptions thrown by the `requests` library, with the following try-except block:

```
 try:
        get = requests.get((requester.batchesUrl)+str(id)+'/', auth=requester.auth)
 except (ConnectionRefusedError, ConnectionError, MaxRetryError) as e:
        print("CAUGHT ECONNECTION ERROR")
        raise type(e)(str(e) + "Additional Info: Method couldn't connect to website, check that your server is running"
                      ).with_traceback(sys.exc_info()[2])
```

But instead of catching the exceptions and adding `"Additional Info:"` to the args, I get `NameError: global name 'MaxRetryError' is not defined.`  Now I know MaxRetryError is an exception in `urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError`.  Must I import these non-built-in exception in order to catch them?  This seems verbose to me considering the number of possible exceptions one is likely to need to watch out for.

**Running:** Python 3.3, Windows 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to handle these three exceptions differently from other exceptions, then yes, you will have to `import` them. (You already have at least one of them, since it's at the top level of `requests`, but the others you may not.)

But do you really need to do that? Trying to restrict yourself to the most detailed exception possible can be as bad as just handling everything. Sometimes both extremes are the right thing to do, but think about what you really want to happen.

If you get a `RequestException`, but it's not a `ConnectionError`, do you really want that to print a traceback and abort, or do you want to log that `CAUGHT ECONNECTION ERROR` and reraise it wrapped in your own type? For that matter, what about an `OSError` that isn't a `RequestException`?

As a side note, do you really get `urllib3.exception.*Error`s from `requests`? I've only seen them wrapped in a `requests.exceptions.RequestException`. (And from a quick look at the source to [`HTTPAdapter.send`](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/master/requests/adapters.py#L312), there's a `except MaxRetryError as e: raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)`, so I think they're *supposed* to be wrapped, and if you're seeing them unwrapped that may be a bug you need to file.)

As another side note, in Python 3.3, you don't have to hack with exception messages like that anymore; you can chain and wrap exceptions, add arguments, etc. See [Exceptions](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/exceptions.html) in the docs for more details. But I think what you want here may be to define your own exception type, then do this:

```
try:
    get = requests.get((requester.batchesUrl)+str(id)+'/', auth=requester.auth)
except OSError as e:
    print("CAUGHT ECONNECTION ERROR")
    raise EConnectionError("Method couldn't connect to website, check that your server is running")
```

That will put the original exception in the `__context__` of your wrapper exception. If you want it in the `__cause__` instead, then `raise EConnectionError(…) from e`. Either way, it'll show up if you format the traceback.

Comment: What an elegant way to add on to the error message.  Thank you for the most thorough answer.

Comment: @joshsvoss: Don't thank me, thank Ka-Ping Yee and the others who invented and implemented exception chaining. :)

Answer (score 5):

You must **always always always** have a name in an accessible scope before you can refer to it without throwing an exception. If that means importing, then so be it.

Answer (score 1):

You must import, etc. in order to catch specific exceptions.

Of course you could simply catch everything.

But the real issue may be that you need to understand why you should catch exceptions.

There are really only few cases I can think of.

1) You catch specific exceptions so that you can respond to them effectively -- If you don't know how to respond to them (requiring an understanding of what they mean and how to respond) -- Since these are generally few in number, this is not a real problem in having to import a number of modules.

2) You catch exceptions so that you can continue processing the next transaction, etc. -- though you abandon the current operation, you may still be able to continue processing acceptablely if the transactions are independent.

3) You catch the exception so that you can log detail, etc. Often re-raising the transaction after you have logged it.

4) You have a top-level exception handler so that you can report the problem in a clean manner to the end-user and possibly do some thing like saving work-in-progress before it is lost.

ADDED

You don't just willy nilly catch exceptions so that you can ignore them unless you like pain.